# Can't target test directory with jest testMatch glob pattern

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, glob, directory-structure

Let's say that I have a project structure like below:

```
src/index.js
src/test/foo.js
test/integration/src/index.test.js
test/unit/src/index.test.js
jest.config.json
```

In `jest.config.json` I have my `testMatch`

```json
{
  "testMatch": [
    "test/**"
  ]
}
```

When I run jest with `--config jest.config.json` it matches with 0 file.

```
  testMatch: test/** - 0 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 5 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

I thought it might be related with some incorrect `rootDir` since `testMatch` is relative to that. I run jest in debug mode to see my root and it seems it's correct. It shows my project directory. (where `jest.config.json` exists)

When I change my `testMatch` to `**/test/**` it can detect my tests in `test/` directory but that's not what I want because then it also matches with `src/test/` directory.

Why it cannot detect my tests in `test/` directory? Is my glob pattern incorrect?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Why it cannot detect my tests in test/ directory? Is my glob pattern incorrect?

Jest's glob implementation has been going through [some](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7108) [issues](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/9464) as of late. Under the hood Jest uses [micromatch](https://github.com/micromatch/micromatch), but why it is getting hung up on relative path globs is unclear.

There are a couple things you can try in your Jest config:

1. Include the [`<rootDir>`](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#rootdir-string) string token directly in your `testMatch` glob like `testMatch: ['<rootDir>/test/**']`.
2. Follow the globstar example more closely from the Jest [testMatch documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testmatch-arraystring), paying attention to the note about glob order:

> Note: Each glob pattern is applied in the order they are specified in the config. (For example ["!**/**fixtures**/**", "**/**tests**/**/*.js"] will not exclude **fixtures** because the negation is overwritten with the second pattern. In order to make the negated glob work in this example it has to come after **/**tests**/**/*.js.)

```js
  testMatch: [
    '**/test/**',
    '!**/src/**'
  ]
```

Comment: For now I used <rootDir>/test/** approach. I don't want to use second because it just excludes src folder.

Comment: I personally would have chosen option 1 myself too.

Comment: thank you sir, adding `rootDir` solved it for me

Comment: "...has been going through some issues as of late..." Those issues are closed. Now why doesn't it work? `test/**` doesn't match anything nor does `./test/**`.

Comment: To exclude you could use `testPathIgnorePatterns` instead.